# linux syntax error-unexpected token near "r"

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, ubuntu-12.04, sar

I am writing a couple of bash scripts which I wish to call within another bash script but I can't seem to get these two examples online to work. It keeps telling me that there is an unexpected error near "r" and one near "mychoice" though it doesn't get resolved when I make the changes. The two classes are to generate a prime numbers test which if it works, I hope to be able to stress a cpu. the other class is just to dynamically select how long to run sar rather than having to hard code in sar 1 30 for example. Does anyone know what is wrong with these classes? Thanks in advance.

```
primetest class

  #!/bin/bash

#
# primes.sh - find all prime numbers up to a certain number
# 2008 - Mike Golvach - eggi@comcast.net
#
# Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 United States License
#

factorial ()  {
 local factorial_count=$1
 if [ "$factorial_count" -eq 0 ]
 then
  factorial_count=1
 fi
 for (( factor=$((factorial_count -1)); $factor >= 1; --factor ))
 do
  factorial_count=$(($factorial_count * $factor))
 done
 echo $factorial_count
}

prime_number ()  {
 local prime=$1
 p_minus_1=$(($prime - 1))
 fact_p_minus_1=`factorial "$p_minus_1"`
 fact_plus_1=$(($fact_p_minus_1 + 1))
 echo $fact_plus_1
}

highest_number=$1

if [ -z $highest_number ]
then
 echo
 echo "Usage: $0 highestNumber"
 echo
 exit 1
fi

if [ $highest_number -eq 0 ]
then
 echo
 echo "Sorry.  0 is not a prime number"
 echo
 exit 0
elif [ $highest_number -eq 1 ]
then
 echo
 echo "Sorry.  0 and 1 are not prime numbers"
 echo
 exit 0
fi

echo "Generating Prime Numbers Up To $highest_number"
if [ $highest_number -eq 2 ]
then
 echo
 echo -n "2" 
else
 echo
 echo -n "2 3 " 
fi

count=4
while [ $count -le $highest_number ]
do
 prime_return=`prime_number "$count"`
 prime_test=$(($prime_return % count))
 if [ $prime_test -eq 0 ]
 then
  echo -n "$count "
 fi
 count=$(($count + 1))
done

echo
echo
echo "All Set!"
echo

exit 0
```

Comment: The tabulation is certainly wrong. If you write code this way, it is difficult to read and people will tend to skip your questions.

Comment: what do you mean? someone already edited it so I presumed that it is formatted correctly now. Do you know where the syntax errors are? They are from a template online.

Comment: Also asked at http://askubuntu.com/q/580836/10127

Comment: There's no 'mychoice' in your code anywhere, and no obvious `r` as well, other than when it's embedded in other vars, like `prime_return`.